# How to pass data included in Activity1 / fragmentA to Activity1 / fragmentB THEN pass it to Activity2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-bundle

I am developping an app with 2 activities.
In my Activity 1 I have a NavigationDrawer which included fragments.
I have Spinners in 2 fragments.

I would like to pass data of Fragment1 and data of Fragment2 to Fragment3 (still in the same activity) THEN code a Button which send data collected in Fragment 3 to Activity 2.

I Can pass data from Activity 1 to Activity 2 no Pb but I don't know how to retrieve data from Fragment then pass them to Activity 2.

I am kind of new in Fragments....

The Code of one of my Fragment including SPINNERS :

```
public static TypeInterventionFragment newInstance() {return (new TypeInterventionFragment()); }


    @Override
    public View  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_type_intervention, container, false);

        mSpinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        mSpinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        mSpinner3 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        mSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedClass = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                switch (selectedClass)
                {
                    case "Constatation du dégat des eaux":
                        // assigning div item list defined in XML to the div Spinner
                        mSpinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sousliste1)));

                        mSpinner3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resultat)));
                        break;

                    case "Relevé humidité":
                        mSpinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sousliste2)));
                        break;

                    case "Thermographie Infrarouge":
                        mSpinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sousliste3)));
                        break;

                    case "Mise en pression":
                        mSpinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sousliste4)));
                        break;

                    case ">Mise en évacuation équipement sanitaire":
                        mSpinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sousliste5)));
                        break;

                    case "Aspersion équipement sanitaire":
                        mSpinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sousliste6)));
                        break;

                    case "Inspection vidéo dans canalisation":
                        mSpinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sousliste7)));
                        break;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

I would like to get selected item from those spinners to me shown in a fragment which included Textview then pass thoses datas to another activity by pressing a button.

If you know how to do it you would probably save my life LOL
I am workinf on it since 2 months

THANKS A LOT
and for my French pal : Merci les amis si vous pouvez m'aider !!!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you instantiate fragments on your activity, you can keep a link to them.
Let's say your ActivityA and your fragment creation block looks like that:

```java
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionA = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionA.replace(R.id.yourFragmentAContainerID, new FragmentA(), "fragmentA");
        fragmentTransactionA.commit();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionB = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionB.replace(R.id.yourFragmentBContainerID, new FragmentB(), "fragmentB");
        fragmentTransactionB.commit();
    }
}
```

Instead of just using `new FragmentA()` or `new FragmentB()`, you could create properties on your activity and assign them the values of your new fragments, effectively creating a link between ActivityA and your fragments.

```java
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentA fragmentA;
    private FragmentB fragmentB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionA = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        fragmentTransactionA.replace(R.id.yourFragmentAContainerID, fragmentA, "fragmentA");
        fragmentTransactionA.commit();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionB = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentB = new FragmentB();
        fragmentTransactionB.replace(R.id.yourFragmentBContainerID, fragmentB, "fragmentB");
        fragmentTransactionB.commit();
    }
}
```

That said, now you can, at any point, get variables from the fragments while you are at your activity. Let's say you want to get "propertyX" of fragment A and "propertyY" of fragment B, you can now just call `fragmentA.getPropertyX()` and `fragmentB.getPropertyY()` at your activity before changing to ActivityB, as long as you have those methods already, and they are public. This is just an example, since we don't have all your code on your question, I took the liberty of creating a sample class.

Please come in if you still need help.

Comment: You sholuld generally 1) add these new fragments only if saved instance state == false, and 2.) you should check the existence of a fragment with findFragmentByTag so that you don't recreate a Fragment that you don't intend to recreate

Comment: That is correct. In my example's case, I placed the fragments' creation at onCreate for the purpose of my explanation, since I didn't have the rest of the OP's code. Thank you for pointing that out @EpicPandaForce.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to communicate between fragments is to create a shared ViewModel object.

Here's a link from the Developer.android.com:

[Communicate with other fragments | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

what you should be looking for is using the Activity as a bridge between your Fragments. It's common practice to utilize interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, 
here is the code of my MainActivity :

```
//FOR DESIGN

private Toolbar toolbar;

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;

//FOR FRAGMENTS
private Fragment fragmentIntro;
private Fragment fragmentPhoto;
private Fragment fragmentProfile;
private Fragment fragmentDossier;
private Fragment fragmentDate;
private Fragment fragmentZone;
private Fragment fragmentTypeIntervention;


//FOR DATAS
private static final int FRAGMENT_INTRO = 0;
private static final int FRAGMENT_PHOTO = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_PROFILE = 2;
private static final int FRAGMENT_DOSSIER = 3;
private static final int FRAGMENT_DATE = 4;
private static final int FRAGMENT_ZONE = 5;
private static final int FRAGMENT_TYPE_INTERVENTION = 6;


// FOR STRINGS

private static TextView mFragmentPageNewsTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Configure all views
    this.configureToolBar();
    this.configureDrawerLayout();
    this.configureNavigationView();

    // Show First Fragment
    this.showFirstFragment();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Handle back click to close menu
    if (this.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        this.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    // Show fragment after user clicked on a menu item
    switch (id){

        case R.id.activity_main_drawer_intro :
            this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_INTRO);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_main_drawer_photo :
            this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_PHOTO);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_main_drawer_profile:
            this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_PROFILE);
            break;
        case R.id.activity_main_drawer_dossier:
            this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_DOSSIER);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_main_drawer_date:
            this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_DATE);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_main_drawer_zone:
            this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_ZONE);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_main_drawer_typeintervention:
            this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_TYPE_INTERVENTION);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    this.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}





// ---------------------
// CONFIGURATION
// ---------------------

// Configure Toolbar
private void configureToolBar(){
    this.toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

// Configure Drawer Layout
private void configureDrawerLayout(){
    this.drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

// Configure NavigationView
private void configureNavigationView(){
    this.navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

// ---------------------
// FRAGMENTS
// ---------------------

// Show first fragment when activity is created
private void showFirstFragment(){
    Fragment visibleFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_main_frame_layout);
    if (visibleFragment == null){
        // Show Photo Fragment
        this.showFragment(FRAGMENT_INTRO);
        // Mark as selected the menu item corresponding to PhotoFragment
        this.navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    }
}

// Show fragment according an Identifier
private void showFragment(int fragmentIdentifier){
    switch (fragmentIdentifier){

        case FRAGMENT_INTRO :
            this.showIntroFragment();
            break;

        case FRAGMENT_PHOTO :
            this.showPhotoFragment();
            break;
        case FRAGMENT_PROFILE:
            this.showProfileFragment();
            break;
        case FRAGMENT_DOSSIER:
            this.showClientsFragment();
            break;

        case FRAGMENT_DATE:
            this.showDateFragment();
            break;

        case FRAGMENT_ZONE:
            this.showZoneFragment();
            break;

        case FRAGMENT_TYPE_INTERVENTION:
            this.showTypeInterventionFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

// ---

// Create each fragment page and show it
private void showIntroFragment() {
    if (this.fragmentIntro == null) this.fragmentIntro = IntroFragment.newInstance();
    this.startTransactionFragment(this.fragmentIntro);
}

private void showPhotoFragment(){
    if (this.fragmentPhoto == null) this.fragmentPhoto = PhotoFragment.newInstance();
    this.startTransactionFragment(this.fragmentPhoto);
}

private void showClientsFragment(){
    if (this.fragmentDossier == null) this.fragmentDossier = DossierFragment.newInstance();
    this.startTransactionFragment(this.fragmentDossier);
}

private void showProfileFragment(){
    if (this.fragmentProfile == null) this.fragmentProfile = ProfileFragment.newInstance();
    this.startTransactionFragment(this.fragmentProfile);
}

private void showDateFragment(){
    if (this.fragmentDate == null) this.fragmentDate = DateFragment.newInstance();
    this.startTransactionFragment(this.fragmentDate);
}

private void showZoneFragment(){
    if (this.fragmentZone == null) this.fragmentZone = ZoneFragment.newInstance();
    this.startTransactionFragment(this.fragmentZone);
}

private void showTypeInterventionFragment(){
    if (this.fragmentTypeIntervention == null) this.fragmentTypeIntervention = TypeInterventionFragment.newInstance();
    this.startTransactionFragment(this.fragmentTypeIntervention);
}



// ---

// Generic method that will replace and show a fragment inside the MainActivity Frame Layout
private void startTransactionFragment(Fragment fragment){
    if (!fragment.isVisible()){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_main_frame_layout, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

}